# C# interview question

Tags: c#

In one of the interview, i got asked the following question but i am not sure what is that, Please help me to understand about the question

Use C# to turn an 4th and 7th bits of a said byte myFlag in which write most bit is first bit.

Comment: Rightmost, not "write most", perhaps?

Comment: "Using C#, turn on the 4th and 7th bits of a `byte` named `myFlag` using the convention of most significant bit being the 1st bit" looks to be the question.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't even try to put any effort in asking a decent question, using decent English, and providing decent and enough details for us to understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Mahendran, buddy we should really work on our English, first.

Comment: It sounds like it wants you to shift the bytes by 4.  Go ahead and study how bytes work and how you can manipulate the bits.  You need to work on your English skills.

Comment: @RobinJ @BurnAfterReading @Ramhound I suspect English is not his/her first language. I agree that an attempt would have been welcome, but let's go easy on the newbies (16 rep).

Comment: Thank you Guvante, what you said is correct. I was about to ask the same.. I will improve my English skill. Thank you for your suggestions friends.

Comment: @Bernhard Mr.Hofmann English is not my first language too and that is why I said "we should" ^^ I had some rough times with explaining my question lately too.That was just a friendly approach of mine.If that was rude I apologise @Mahendran.

Answer (score 2):

Each byte has 8 bits, which are either on (1) or off (0). So you'd want to turn on the specified bits, using the bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1):

how about ORing with 72 (01001000) ?

```
myFlag  = myFlag | 72;
```

Comment: This returns the right value however it doesn't modify the flags. `myFlag = myFlag | 72;` may be what the interviewer wants.

Comment: Which can be shortened even to `myFlag |= 72;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my interpretation is correct you are looking to use bit-wise operators to solve the problem. In order to ensure a particular bit is on use `|` with the bits set that you want set.

```
myFlag = myFlag | 0b00010010
```

Or equivalently

```
myFlag |= 18
```

Comment: If the "rightmost" bit is the first bit, wouldn't the 4th and 7th bit be 0b01001000 (decimal value 72)?

Comment: @user79878: I was assuming they were using the convention of most significant bit is the first bit.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how to declare "myFlag", but this should be what you're looking for.

```
[Flags]
enum BitFlags : byte
{
    One = ( 1 << 0 ),
    Two = ( 1 << 1 ),
    Three = ( 1 << 2 ),
    Four = ( 1 << 3 ),
    Five = ( 1 << 4 ),
    Six = ( 1 << 5 ),
    Seven = ( 1 << 6 ),
    Eight = ( 1 << 7 )
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BitFlags myFlag = BitFlags.Four | BitFlags.Seven;

    Console.WriteLine( Convert.ToString( ( byte ) myFlag, 2 ) );
}
```

Edit: Updated for C# clarity and used "[Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)" attribute, which is probably more along the lines of what the interviewer was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps to see the string of bytes, then you can use the Convert class to convert integers to bit strings and reverse to help visualise the effects of the bitwise OR. Below is a sample that creates a **toggledOnFlag** that has the bits toggled on. You could OR with the other bit string to switch them off.

```
var toggleBitsOn  = "01001000";
var toggleBitsOff = "10110111";
var toggle = Convert.ToInt32(toggleBitsOn, 2);

var toggledOnFlag = myFlag | toggle;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(toggledOnFlag, 2));
```